# When building a MACOSX_BUNDLE in CMake, how to copy the linked dynamic libraries into the bundle?

Tags: macos, cmake, dylib

We build an OS X application, released in a .app bundle. The build management is implemented using CMake. This application depends on both *CMake target* libraries (possibly imported) and libraries available in the `xxx_LIBRARIES`variables populated by *Findxxx.cmake* scripts. An outline of the CMakeLists.txt could be:

```
project(OSX_Bundle)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} MACOSX_BUNDLE main.mm )

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}  PRIVATE
                           ${LibA_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
                      ${LibA_LIBRARIES}
                      LibB
                      "-framework Cocoa" )
```

Now, we need to copy both *LibA.dylib* and *LibB.dylib* into the canonical *OSX_Bundle.app/Contents/Frameworks*. This copy should be done for the app in the build tree, as well as in the install tree. Even though it would appear as a basic task, we cannot find a good resource online explaining the best way(s) of solving this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CMake: Copy Frameworks into App Bundle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944376/cmake-copy-frameworks-into-app-bundle)

Comment: @Hasturkun Thank you for the link. Sadly it seems that fixup_bundle only applies to the install tree (at least that what I am inferring from all the example using it in an `INSTALL` command).

Comment: I haven't used it, but it looks like `FIXUP_BUNDLE` works in place so I think it should work for you (but again, I haven't tested it)

Comment: I would recommend using bash to grab libraries and adjust install names.

Answer (score -2):

Many people face this issue. You can try one of this list:

- [CMake post-buld command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events) and invoke "macdeployqt" here; but it may slowdown the build (CMake generator expressions will give you correct path and binary for Xcode/VS as well)
- or [CMake custom command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html), again with macdeployqt, if you don't want trigger it always, then it can be manually triggered wheen needed
- it is possible bundle dependencies on install stage as mentioned in above comments
- it is possible to use CPack, it will give you new 'package' target; after playing with CMake/CPack it may bundle everything needed (it use install stuff mentioned above) and generate a final installer

I guess, the last bullet should fit your needs.

Comment: Introducing Qt as a dependency is a big ask.

Comment: Bundling Qt libs work smooth, the only pain are Qt plugins e.g. QtQuick stuff that is still open/discussed in bugreports after many years... (i.e. it requires custom steps to bundle all stuff inside final binary)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Qt, which is why I think introducing it as a dependency to a project just to use *macdeployqt* is not a good solution.

Comment: Using `macdeployqt` wouldn’t necessarily introduce any Qt dependencies, it does not officially support third-party libs (although sometimes it works).