# Using CMake to copy .frameworks to iOS app bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, cmake

A library I'm using recently switched to distribution as a .framework.

In my existing CMake file, I've been successful at getting it to link with my iOS app, but am getting:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Pizza.framework/Pizza
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/D71ED298-C287-4B2F-8AFA-710A14C06D75/pizzashop.app/pizza
  Reason: image not found
```

when I install it from Xcode.  If I manually add it to my xcode project, in the "embedded binaries" section then I'm good (see image below)

[image]

So I've concluded that the problem is getting the .framework into my app bundle.  I've come across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944376/cmake-copy-frameworks-into-app-bundle) and looked at the linked QT example, but I'm still trying to orient myself here as I'm finding the syntax a bit opaque.

Is CMake's BundleUtilities what I want to use here?  In looking at the BundleUtilities example I'm a bit lost:

```
set(APPS ...)  # paths to executables
set(DIRS ...)   # directories to search for prerequisites
INSTALL(CODE "
   include(BundleUtilities)
   fixup_bundle(\"${APPS}\"   \"\"   \"${DIRS}\")
   " COMPONENT Runtime)
```

Is this OSX-specific or can I apply it similarly to iOS?

Comment: I have the same problem. As far as I understand, FIXUP_BUNDLE should be ideal for this. However, it doesn't look like it is built to deal with iOS bundle layouts.

Comment: @EmilStyrke its been on my TODO list for a while to post the answer, your pain has spurred me to move it up in priority :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We didn't end up finding an ideal solution, and ended up doing things a bit more manually than preferred:

1. We added a custom command we run after the build is complete, but before it is packaged (see CMake's `add_custom_command`).
2. The custom command does the following:

   - creates a Frameworks directory under our app bundle folder (make sure it's somewhere where it will get copied in your packaging process).
   - we use `cp -aH` to copy all frameworks into this Frameworks directory
   - we then re-sign each framework in this directory using: 
     `codesign --force --verbose Computers.framework --sign "$2"`
3. Add the Frameworks directory to your search paths:

```cpp
set_target_properties(${EXE_NAME} PROPERTIES 
        XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS "@executable_path/Frameworks")
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very similar to what I ended up doing, but I also had to re-sign the bundle itself, since subsequent builds seem to skip bundle signing  but still run the custom command. Not sure if this is a problem with CMake or XCode.

Comment: What's the ***$2*** after the `--sign`?

Comment: Your signing ID.