# How to get CMake to embed a private framework into a macOS app bundle?

Tags: cmake

target_link_libraries links private frameworks fine but it doesn't have a way to copy the frameworks into the app bundle's Frameworks directory. It also doesn't have a way to then update the executable's path to the framework.

So essentially I need CMake to:

1. Link with a private dylib.
2. Copy that dylib into the app bundle's Frameworks directory.
3. Update the executable's path to the dylib.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMake: Copy Frameworks into App Bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944376/cmake-copy-frameworks-into-app-bundle)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn’t.

Answer (score 3):

I decided to write my own rpaths to the final executable. To prevent CMake from writing build rpaths set `CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH`. This needs to be set before add_executable.

```
set(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH TRUE)
```

Then I copy all the dylibs I want to embed into the built app bundle's Frameworks directory. In this case I'm copying MoltenVK which is being stored in the project. `${PROJECT_NAME}` is the executable name.

```
set(APP_BUNDLE_CONTENTS_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.app/Contents")
set(APP_BUNDLE_FRAMEWORKS_DIR "${APP_BUNDLE_CONTENTS_DIR}/Frameworks")

file(GLOB VULKAN_DYLIB_PATHS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/vulkan/builds/mac/*")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${VULKAN_DYLIB_PATHS})
file(COPY ${VULKAN_DYLIB_PATHS} DESTINATION ${APP_BUNDLE_FRAMEWORKS_DIR})
```

Then I add an rpath to the executable as a post build command.

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} 
    POST_BUILD COMMAND 
    install_name_tool -add_rpath "@executable_path/../Frameworks/"
    "${APP_BUNDLE_CONTENTS_DIR}/MacOS/${PROJECT_NAME}")
```

This works for building and debugging with CMake. This won't work when generating an Xcode project. Hopefully I'll find a better cleaner way, but this works for now.

Comment: For some reason the `install_name_tool` part did not work for me. I only have one .dylib file so I had to change it to `install_name_tool -change X.dylib @executable_path/../Frameworks/X.dylib App.app/Contents/MacOS/Executable`